# File (products) of a kernel cross compilation

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

When the kernel is cross compiled (example. `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`), what are the newly created files and their meanings?

I'm not looking for a detailed explanation of each new file, just looking to get a conceptual overview of the structure and purpose of special files.

---

In parallel, I'm doing a git versioned kernel build to see what new files will arrive.Will update once it's done.

Comment: Did the comparison. There are lots of .o files. However, the zImage acts as is it is't a new file. vmlinux is created normally.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not looking for a detailed explanation of each new file, just looking to get a conceptual overview of the structure and purpose of special files.

There are only two you need to be concerned about, `[src]/arch/[your arch]/boot/bzImage` -- that is the kernel<sup>1</sup> -- and `[src]/System.map`, which is less important, but probably something you want installed properly.  It contains the symbol table for the kernel, used in debugging (including logged errors/oops) to (e.g.) map addresses to function names.  So, not necessary, but useful.

`System.map` should be installed to `/boot` as `System.map-[release string]` where "release string" is what that kernel reports via `uname -r`.

Most of the other files generated during compilation are more-or-less ordinary intermediate object (`.o`) files; they are internal to the build process.  There could be hundreds or thousands of them, and if you are curious about one in particular, look at its corresponding `.c` file (of course, if you don't speak C, there's probably not much to be interested in), etc.  These files are all left behind in the build directory; the kernel does not link to or install any libraries.  There are also a few executable tools built, but again, these are internal to the process.  They have no subsequent use and are not installed anywhere.

The only things installed besides bzImage and System.map are the various `.ko` files; these are the modules that go into `/lib/modules/[release string]`.

If you are curious about anything, the best place to start is `grep -R` on the `[src]/Documentation` directory.  If you want a perspective on the individual documentation files, check the listings in `[src]/Documentation/00-INDEX`.

---

<sup>1. And, presuming the appropriate drivers are built in (so you don't need an initramfs), that's all you actually need.  The kernel is a **singular, stand-alone, bare metal** binary executable.  It is only **one file**, although it can load modular components (.ko files) while running.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you expand it with a case where initramfs and device trees are needed?

Comment: @Alan When you are compiling a kernel for multiple machines, modules make sense because that way your kernel can be smaller and hardware configuration can be determined at boot instead of at compile they also make sense with removable hardware like usb devices. initramfs is needed when your root filesystem is stored on am non bootable device such as one that is compiled as a module, lvm, or raid.

Comment: Found this regarding initramfs: `The 2.6 kernel build process always creates a gzipped cpio format initramfs
archive and links it into the resulting kernel binary`.  [Ref.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)

Comment: From `ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt` -> right you are!  I always target a machine specifically when building, and so have not bothered with an initramfs since before "initramfs" existed -- i.e., the days of the "initrd".  I was also fooled by the fact that contemporary mainstream distros do use an external initramfs in `/boot`, however, there's probably an obvious reason for that, namely they can vary the initramfs (or customize it to your system) without using different kernels.  You should ask a separate question if you are curious about these details.